# how do i fetchone() or fetchall() sqlite3 and store them as str in a var using python

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to get a value from sqlite3 and convert it to a string and store it in a variable

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
database = conn.cursor()

u = 'ZERO'
all_data = str(database.execute("SELECT * FROM logs where loguser =? ", (u,)).fetchone())
```

Results:

> (5, 'ZERO', hello there !')

I tried :

```
x = ''.join(all_data)

print(x)
```

What I'm hoping for :

> 5 ZERO hello there !

Comment: So, what's wrong with your code? Getting an error? An invalid value for `all_data` (like `Ǹone`)? Explain further please

Comment: if i print (all_data) I get a tuple, i need it as a string

Comment: Can you give an example output? Your way should properly convert it to a string of a tuple. **Edit:** Preferably an example of both the current output and the desired output.

Comment: when I print(all_data), I get (5, 'ZERO', 'hello this is a test !')
I need it as a pure string..

so it prints out like 5 ZERO hello this is a test !


I even tried :
x = ''.join(all_data)

print(x)

Comment: That is a string. For example, this: `print('(1, 2, 3)')` will output: `(1, 2, 3)`, which looks like a tuple since `print()` doesn't output the quotes, but it was still a string. If you try: `print(repr(all_data))` you'll see that it's a string and it has the quotation marks around it. Your string just looks like this: `"(5, 'ZERO', 'hello this is a test !')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `fetchone()`, you get a tuple back, which represents the row in your database table, so that column's value is an element in the tuple:

```
(5, 'ZERO', 'hello there !')
```

Which you then converted to a string with `str()`:

```
>>> all_data = str((5, 'ZERO', 'hello there !'))
>>> all_data
"(5, 'ZERO', 'hello there !')"
```

And you converted it to a string before you stored the value to `all_data`, which is why your `''.join()` did nothing:

```
>>> ''.join('abcdefg')
'abcdefg'
```

You clearly don't want the commas and parenthesis, so we shouldn't convert the result of `fetchone()` to a string in the first place. Let's just get the tuple first:

```
>>> data = database.execute(...).fetchone()
>>> data
(5, 'ZERO', 'hello there !')
```

Now join the tuple's elements together, separated with spaces (as you've asked) using:

```
' '.join(data)
```

This will not work if you have non-string elements in the tuple (in your case the `5`), so you need to convert everything to strings before you join them. I recommend using a comprehension:

```
' '.join(str(column) for column in data)
```

This will give you the desired final string:

```
>>> data_str = ' '.join(str(x) for x in data)
>>> data_str
'5 ZERO hello there !'
```

Comment: I know it says not to say thank you... but I really appreciate the time and effort you put in this !